# Expressing a curve function in a linear way

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Given the following function which expresses the relationship between $y$ and $t$  with constant factors $k$, $a$ and $b$:

$y=ke^{-\frac{t}{ab}}$

Obtain another equation such that there is a linear relationship between $y$ and $t$.

I know that I need to obtain something of the form $y=mx+b$ and I don't even know if this is possible for other type of functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

for $t$ close to $a$,

$$f(t)\approx f(a)+(t-a)f'(a)$$